# Issue with generic conversion method using RxSwift

Tags: swift, generics, rx-swift, objectmapper

I have this result datatype called  which wraps a type and a progress

```
public enum <T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Progress(CGFloat)
}

class func rx_request(router: Router) -> Observable<<AnyObject>>
```

This `AnyObject` needs to be transformed into a `Mappable` structure (ObjectMapper), so because I have several of these Mappable structs, I wanted to achieve something like this, a generic map that I can use:

```
class func rx_convert<T : Mappable>(value: <AnyObject>) -> Observable<<T>> {

        return Observable.create { observer in

            switch value {
            case .Success(let object):
                guard let convertedObject = Mapper<T>().map(object) else {
                    observer.onError(NetworkError.IncorrectDataReturned)
                    return NopDisposable.instance
                }

                observer.on(.Next(<T>.Success(convertedObject)))
                observer.on(.Completed)

            case .Progress(let progress):
                observer.on(.Next(<T>.Progress(progress)))
                break
            }

            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
}
```

It seems the above definition is wrong because this cannot be compiled: `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function`

```
.flatMapLatest({ _ in
    .rx_request(Router.Pipeline)
})
.flatMapLatest({ result -> Observable<<ResponsePipeline>> in
    .rx_convert<ResponsePipeline>(result)
    // Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
})
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.flatMapLatest({ result -> Observable<<ResponsePipeline>> in
    return .rx_convert(result)
})
```

Because the closure passed to `flatMapLatest` is already typed to return an `Observable<<ResponsePipeline>>`, compiler can infer the type for `rx_convert` to be `<AnyObject> -> Observable<<ResponsePipeline>>` so you can drop `<ResponsePipeline>` from the call.

Comment: @AndreiPopa you should accept his answer as the correct answer by clicking on the green checkmark.